# How to get this logic in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, join, authentication, self

I have two tables to track user activity:

[image]

I need to write a SQL query to get data in below format

:
UserId|UserRole|LoginTime|LogOutTime

Note : LoginTime/LogOutTime is Activity_Time_Stamp in ActivityAuditTrail table. I am not able to figure out a logic for this.

Comment: Added a new column User_Session in Activity_Audit_Trail table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT User_Id, User_Role, Activity_Time_Stamp AS LoginTime, 
( SELECT Activity_Time_Stamp 
  FROM ActivityAuditTrail aud2
  WHERE aud2.Activity_Id=2 
  AND ActivityAuditTrail.User_Id=aud2.User_Id 
  AND ActivityAuditTrail.User_Session=aud2.User_Session 
) AS LogOutTime
FROM ActivityAuditTrail
WHERE Activity_Id=1
```

I'm being on the safe side and assuming that sessions are not unique to a user, but if they are you may be able to leave out the user_id from the WHERE entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with LoginTime AS(
SELECT User_Id, Activity_Time_Stamp 
  FROM Activity_Audit_Trail
 WHERE Activity_Id = 01
),LogOutTime AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.User_Id ORDER BY Sa.User_Id, a.Activity_Time_Stamp DESC) AS RowNumber
       a.User_Id, a.Activity_Time_Stamp AS LogOutTimeValue, li.Activity_Time_Stamp AS LoginTimeValue
  FROM Activity_Audit_Trail a
  JOIN LoginTime li
    ON li.User_Id =  a.User_Id
 WHERE Activity_Id = 02
   AND a.Activity_Time_Stamp > li.Activity_Time_Stamp
     ) 
  Select User_Id
  ,User_Role
  ,LoginTimeValue
  ,LogOutTimeValue
FROM LogOutTime
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Please try this.. As i don't have schema script of tables, not tested. You may get some syntax errors. Please follow the logic..

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.User_Id ORDER BY Sa.User_Id, a.Activity_Time_Stamp DESC) Try this way

Answer (score 1):

Try by grouping the rows in the `ActivityAuditTrail` user, role and session token and then select the lowest and highest activity timestamps as the login and logout timestamps respectively:

```
SELECT User_Id, User_Role, MIN(Activity_Time_Stamp) AS LoginTime, CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 2 THEN MAX(Activity_Time_Stamp) ELSE NULL END AS LogOutTime
FROM ActivityAuditTrail
GROUP BY User_Id, User_Role, User_Session
```

This query will get you the login and logout timestamps for each user session.

Comment: Thanks Enrico, but the above query is not correct.Where have you taken consideration of Activity table ActivityID needs to be used to check for Login or Logout

Comment: @AJ01 In this case I'm assuming that the `ActivityAuditTrail` table will only contain a single *login/logout* pair of rows per *user/role* at any given time. With this premise it's safe to assume that the lowest timestamp recorded for a user with a given role will be a *login*, while the highest timestamp will be a *logout*. If the table records multiple login/logout events for the same user, which I suspect is the case, then we need an additional piece of information to uniquely identify a session.

Comment: Added a new column User_Session in Activity_Audit_Trail table

Comment: @AJ01 Cool. Now we can just include the session token in the grouping and we'll get the login/logout timestamps for each user session. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey Enrico, Tried your query but its not giving the desired result. What i want is When user  logs in it ie ActivityId=1 the ActivityTimestamp is updated at that time the Logout time will be null so when the user logs off ie ActivityId=2 the Actvitytime stamp in Logut column.

Comment: SELECT Audit_1.User_Id, 
            Audit_1.User_Role, 
            Audit_1.Activity_Time_Stamp AS Login_Time_Stamp,
            Audit_2.Activity_Time_Stamp AS Logoff_Time_Stamp
      FROM ED.Activity_Audit_Trail AS Audit_1
            LEFT JOIN ED.Activity_Audit_Trail AS Audit_2
                  ON Audit_1.User_Session = Audit_2.User_Session
                        AND Audit_2.Activity_Id = 2
      WHERE Audit_1.Activity_Id = 1 --Login type

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need your activity table.
This query will give you wat you need IF thee user has logged in and out of the system only once:

```
Select AT.UserId. AT.UserRole, MIN(Activity_Time_Stamp) as LoginTime, MAX(Activity_Time_Stamp) as LogoutTime
from ActivityAuditTrail AT
group by AT.UserId. AT.UserRole
```

of course thats not enough, so youll need a way to group a login with a logout.
I assume thats what the Activity_ID field is for. So each activity is composed of several activity audit trails where the firs is the login and the last is the logout
In that case you can run this:

```
Select AT.UserId. AT.UserRole, AT.Activity_ID, MIN(Activity_Time_Stamp) as LoginTime, MAX(Activity_Time_Stamp) as LogoutTime
from ActivityAuditTrail AT
group by AT.UserId. AT.UserRole, AT.Activity_ID
```

EDIT:

```
select distinct AT.UserId, AT.UserRole,
(select Activity_Time_Stamp from ActivityAuditTrail where UserId=AT.UserId and Activity_ID=1) as LoginTime,
(select Activity_Time_Stamp from ActivityAuditTrail where UserId=AT.UserId and Activity_ID=2) as LogoutTime
from ActivityAuditTrail AT
```

Comment: Added a new column User_Session in Activity_Audit_Trail table

Comment: what will you use it for? Control the login\logout?

Comment: See my edit. I may help.
Again that will work if a user has only one log in and log out. You will need a way to isolate the logins and logouts by a session

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.UserId, b.User_Role MIN(b.Activity_Time_Stamp) AS LoginTime, MAX(b.Activity_Time_Stamp) AS LogoutTime  
FROM `Activity` a 
  INNER JOIN `Activity Audit Trail` b ON a.Id = b.Activity_Id 
GROUP BY b.User_Id
```

Comment: Have you understood the question? The above is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

How to identify a whole session, I mean, maybe a user have logged in and logged out for several times, how to know which LogOut match which Login.

Comment: That's a great catch really i haven't thought of this. Lemme figure out this first

Comment: Added a new column User_Session in Activity_Audit_Trail table

Comment: Then another question, in this logic, is the Activity table necessary?